# copied folder break inheritance fails

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

When i copy the folder with in same document library and trying to break inheritance it fails. below is the code for the same. Can any one help on the same

```
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"

Function Copy-SPOFolder([String]$SiteURL, [String]$SourceFolderURL, [String]$TargetFolderURL)
{
$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = “ReuseThread”
    Try{
        #Copy the Folder
        $MoveCopyOpt = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyOptions
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyUtil]::CopyFolder($ctx, $SourceFolderURL, $TargetFolderURL, $MoveCopyOpt)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-host -f Green "Folder Copied Successfully!" }
    Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Copying the Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
function Connect-SPO()
{
param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][string]$Username,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)][string]$Url,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]$AdminPassword)
$global:ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $AdminPassword)
$ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
#Function to Get Folder Permissions
Function Get-SPOFolderPermission([String]$SiteURL, [String]$FolderRelativeURL)
{
$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = “ReuseThread”
    Try{


        #Get the Folder
        $Folder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderRelativeURL)
        $ctx.Load($Folder)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Get permissions assigned to the Folder
        $RoleAssignments = $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments
        $ctx.Load($RoleAssignments)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Loop through each permission assigned and extract details
        $PermissionCollection = @()
        Foreach($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments)
        {
            $ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.Member)
            $ctx.executeQuery()

            #Get the User Type
            $PermissionType = $RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType

            #Get the Permission Levels assigned
            $ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            $PermissionLevels = ($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","

            #Get the User/Group Name
            $Name = $RoleAssignment.Member.Title # $RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName

            #Add the Data to Object
            $Permissions = New-Object PSObject
            $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty Name($Name)
            $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty Type($PermissionType)
            $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty PermissionLevels($PermissionLevels)
            $PermissionCollection += $Permissions
        }
        Return $PermissionCollection
    }
    Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Getting Folder Permissions!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
    #variables

    $admin="username"
    $pass= ConvertTo-SecureString "PassWord" -AsPlainText -Force
    $SiteURL="https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/hdemo/"
    $LibraryName="FolderTest";
    $SrcFolderName="RootLibrary"
    $NewFolderName="RootLibrary5"
    $global:ctx
    Try {
            Connect-SPO -Username $admin -Url $site -AdminPassword $pass
            $Library=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName);
            $Folders = $Library.RootFolder.Folders
            $ctx.Load($Library);
            $ctx.Load($Folders)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()        
       #Get existing folder names
            $FolderNames = $Folders | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
            if($FolderNames -contains $NewFolderName)
            {
                write-host "Folder Exists Already!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }

            else{

                       $SourceFolderURL= $SiteURL + $LibraryName +"/" + $SrcFolderName
                       $TargetFolderURL= $SiteURL + $LibraryName +"/" + $NewFolderName 
                        Copy-SPOFolder $SiteURL $SourceFolderURL $TargetFolderURL
                        $ctx.Load($Library);
                        $ctx.Load($Folders)
                        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                        $FolderNames = $Folders | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
            if($FolderNames -contains $NewFolderName)
            {
            $FolderRelativeURL= "/sites/hgs_demo/"+ $LibraryName +"/" + $NewFolderName
               # write-host "Folder Exists Already!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
               $cFolder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderRelativeURL)
               $ctx.Load($cFolder)
               $cx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Break Permission inheritence - Remove all existing list permissions & keep Item level permissions
        $Folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($False,$True)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-host -f Yellow "Folder's Permission inheritance broken..."
        Get-SPOFolderPermission $SiteURL $FolderRelativeURL
                      }}}

    Catch {
            write-host -f Red "Error Granting permission to  Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
          }
```

Comment: What’s the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the PowerShell as below.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll"

Function Copy-SPOFolder([String]$SiteURL, [String]$SourceFolderURL, [String]$TargetFolderURL)
{
    $Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    Try{
        #Copy the Folder
        $MoveCopyOpt = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyOptions
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyUtil]::CopyFolder($ctx, $SourceFolderURL, $TargetFolderURL, $MoveCopyOpt)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-host -f Green "Folder Copied Successfully!" }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Copying the Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
function Connect-SPO()
{
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][string]$Username,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)][string]$Url,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]$AdminPassword)
    $global:ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $AdminPassword)
    $ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
#Function to Get Folder Permissions
Function Get-SPOFolderPermission([String]$SiteURL, [String]$FolderRelativeURL)
{
    $Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    Try{


        #Get the Folder
        $Folder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderRelativeURL)
        $ctx.Load($Folder)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Get permissions assigned to the Folder
        $RoleAssignments = $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments
        $ctx.Load($RoleAssignments)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Loop through each permission assigned and extract details
        $PermissionCollection = @()
        Foreach($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments)
        {
            $ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.Member)
            $ctx.executeQuery()

            #Get the User Type
            $PermissionType = $RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType

            #Get the Permission Levels assigned
            $ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            $PermissionLevels = ($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","

            #Get the User/Group Name
            $Name = $RoleAssignment.Member.Title # $RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName

            #Add the Data to Object
            $Permissions = New-Object PSObject
            $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty Name($Name)
            $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty Type($PermissionType)
            $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty PermissionLevels($PermissionLevels)
            $PermissionCollection += $Permissions
        }
        Return $PermissionCollection
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Getting Folder Permissions!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
#variables

$admin="username"
$pass= ConvertTo-SecureString "PassWord" -AsPlainText -Force
$SiteURL="https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/hdemo/"
$LibraryName="FolderTest";
$SrcFolderName="RootLibrary"
$NewFolderName="RootLibrary5"
$global:ctx
Try {
    Connect-SPO -Username $admin -Url $SiteURL -AdminPassword $pass
    $Library=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName);
    $Folders = $Library.RootFolder.Folders
    $ctx.Load($Library);
    $ctx.Load($Folders)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()        
    #Get existing folder names
    $FolderNames = $Folders | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
    if($FolderNames -contains $NewFolderName)
    {
        write-host "Folder Exists Already!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else{
        $SourceFolderURL= $SiteURL + $LibraryName +"/" + $SrcFolderName
        $TargetFolderURL= $SiteURL + $LibraryName +"/" + $NewFolderName 
        Copy-SPOFolder $SiteURL $SourceFolderURL $TargetFolderURL
        $ctx.Load($Library);
        $ctx.Load($Folders)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $FolderNames = $Folders | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        if($FolderNames -contains $NewFolderName)
        {
            $FolderRelativeURL= "/sites/hdemo/"+ $LibraryName +"/" + $NewFolderName
            # write-host "Folder Exists Already!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $cFolder = $ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderRelativeURL)
            $ctx.Load($cFolder)
            $cx.ExecuteQuery()

            #Break Permission inheritence - Remove all existing list permissions & keep Item level permissions
            $Folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($False,$True)
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-host -f Yellow "Folder's Permission inheritance broken..."
            Get-SPOFolderPermission $SiteURL $FolderRelativeURL
        }
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Granting permission to  Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

If still not works, we can remove the try...catch in the code, and check which line of script throw the exception, and get more error message.